# ASP.NET and IIS 7.5 - HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I try to configure IIS 7.5 on a new server (Windows Server 2008 R2), in order to run an ASP.NET 4.0 application. Two "domains" are defined on the server (managed with Parallels Plesk), each one appearing as a site in IIS. One domain is for the public site, the other is used for tests. At the present time, the DNS of the test site points to that new server while the DNS of the public site still points to our old server. We transfer the test site first, to see if everything is OK, before transfering the public site to the new server.

Pointing to the test site in IIS, if I run the Browse command on the folder of the application, I get the HTTP Error 403.14, with the message: *The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory*. The strange thing is this: if I put the exact same folder structure in the other domain on the same server, and I run the same Browse command, I see the default page of the application (I don't know if everything works after that but, at least, the first page shows up as expected). I should add:

- Both sites use the same application pool.
- Both sites have the same permissions (I checked one by one, also compared with cacls)
- The default page is not set in IIS but is the authentication form specified in Web.config

So, same setup but different results. I don't know if there is something else that I should check. I am on very shaky ground when I talk about server configuration and IIS; so I hope that this description is clear enough and makes sense.

Comment: In view of the actual cause of the problem, this is a question that I would like to delete (it is of not use for other people). But I haven't found a way to remove one of my own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it. It probably doesn't work for both sites on the new server. When I run the Browse command, it shows the page in IE using the DNS of the site. Since the DNS of the public site still points to the old server, the page displayed in IE is not from the folder that I clicked, but rather from the old server site.

I can now look for standard solutions to the 403.14 problem on the new server...